# Unable to view application in localhost

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile, docker-container, docker-image

I am working on Docker!
I want to create a customized docker image for an angular application using Dockerfile.
I am able to create the image and able to run the container where my container is up & running but i am not able to view the application in my localhost.

**My Docker file:**

```
base image FROM node:10.15.1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq google-chrome-stable

set working directory RUN mkdir /usr/src/app WORKDIR /usr/src/app

add `/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

install and cache app dependencies COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json RUN npm install RUN npm install -g
@angular/cli@7.3.1

add app COPY . /usr/src/app

start app CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000.
```

The error I am getting in localhost:

```
This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.
Search Google for localhost 5000 home
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Can someone help me with the solution?

Comment: You didn't expose your docker port, meaning your OS can't communicate with Docker.

Comment: Also, you should have a bash command line instead of a node one, as you will be running `ng serve` and not running any node command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to you docker file, I assume your application is running on port 5000 inside the docker container. To reach your app from localhost, you need to map the port 5000 of container to the localhost's port 5000. You can do this while running the image with the following command:`docker run --name <your_container_name> -p 5000:5000 <image_name>`